# Missing property at client side Nodejs

Tags: node.js, object, mongoose, server

My simple problem is:

I had an mongoose object at server side:

`...
item = {
  name: "Test",
  id: 1
}`

// item was an mongo schema

// id and name was define in model `String` and `Number`

Then I add into `item` new field `mentions`:

`item.mention = [{ id: 1, ... }]`

But I can't get `mention` at client side.

My response code:

`res,json({ status: 1, message: 'success', data: item })`

The response was `data: { name: "Test", id: 1 }`

I don't want to add `mention` into my mongo schema.

So, what's my problem?

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `item` is a [MongooseDocument](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js), not a plain javascript object.

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want.

**1)** Using [.lean()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)

> Documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain
>   javascript objects, not MongooseDocuments

```
Model.findOne().lean().exec((err, item) => {
    item.mention = [{ id: 1 }];
    res.json(item);
});
```

**This option will increase the performance since you ignore the overhead of creating the Mongoose Document**

**2)** Using: `.set()`

```
item.set('mention', [{ id: 1}], { strict: false });
```

**4)** Using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
res.json({
    status: 1,
    message: 'success',
    data: { mention: [{ id: 5 }], ...item }
})
```

**4)** Using `Object.assign` as @Alexis Facques explained.

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of `Object.assign()` should resolve your problem too.

```
res.json({
    status: 1,
    message: 'success',
    data: Object.assign({ mention: [{id: 1...}] },item)
})
```